# Android App Deployment Status list?

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api

I am deploying several apps to the Google Play Store and I'd like to be able to check their status without entering into the google play developer console. I'd like to be able to check the status of the app, but I can't find a curated list of the different statuses that an android app can enter. Clearly when I first upload my app it enters into the "Draft" status and when I submit for processing it enters "Pending Publication".

What are all the statuses that an app can be in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered on [Google Play Support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282)

> **Draft**: App hasn't been published on Google Play.
>
> **Pending publication**: App is currently being processed for publishing.
>
> **Published**: App is published and available on Google Play.
>
> **Rejected**: App has been rejected and wasn't published due to a
>   violation of Google Play policies. More information about the
>   violation is available near the top of your app's pages on the
>   Developer Console. Once you make a change to your app to address the
>   violation, you can submit it again.
>
> **Suspended**: App is suspended due to a violation of Google Play Policies
>   (Content Policy, Developer Distribution Agreement). An email with
>   details about the suspension is sent to the account owner.